# Google Earth Engine script change

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vegetation-index

[image: vegetation script]I'm hoping to use the monitoring forest vegetation condition script in GEE. The example given is using the protected areas polygons but I'm trying to use this script across Brazil or a Brazilian state. I'm wondering how id edit this script to do so. Please find script below:

```js
// Get MODIS 250m vegetation data.
var mod13 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1');

// Get features of the forest national parks.
var nps = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/202006/polygons')
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME', ['Bandipur', 'Rajiv Gandhi (Nagarhole)']))
```

Comment: Do you have the polygons of your study area? If so, upload it as an asset and then call the asset instead of the feature collection of the example

Comment: ah no I haven't i'll try give this a go thank you

Comment: Would this be right ? Sorry  I’m new to all this.                             Get MODIS 250m vegetation data.
var mod13 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1');

// Get features of the forest national parks.
var nps = ee.geometry 
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME', [‘rondonia']))

Comment: `ee.geometry` should be replaced by `ee.FeatureCollection('users/yourfolder/yourimage')`. Check this link for more information about custom assets: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager

Comment: Thank you, I’ll check it out :)